# How to use form for with polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to make a form on my new.html.erb page and it is giving me a undefined method `task_presentations_path' error.

```
= form_tag [@task, Presentation.new] do |f|
    = f.label :summary
    = f.text_field :summary
```

tasks_controller

```
def new
    @task = Task.new
end
```

routes

```
resources :presentations do
        resources :tasks
    end
```

task model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :taskable, polymorphic: true
  has_one :task_type
  has_one :task_status
end
```

presentation model

```
class Presentation < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tasks, as: :taskable
end
```

rake tasks

```
          presentation_tasks GET      /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks(.:format)               tasks#index
                             POST     /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks(.:format)               tasks#create
       new_presentation_task GET      /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks/new(.:format)           tasks#new
      edit_presentation_task GET      /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)      tasks#edit
           presentation_task GET      /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#show
                             PATCH    /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#update
                             PUT      /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#update
                             DELETE   /presentations/:presentation_id/tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#destroy
```

Comment: I would run `bundle exec rake routes | grep task` and see what that route is called. Looks like it might be presentation_tasks_path but I'm not sure

Comment: Can you add more information of the controller and the model..?

Comment: yes I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

As your `task` model is a `nested` resource of `presentation`,**Originally** it should only exists when there is `presentation` model is present. So...

```
####### in the controller.

def new
   @presentation  = Presentation.find(params[:id])   
   @task = @presentation.tasks.new
end

###### in your view
= form_tag [@presentation,@task] do |f|
   ....
   ....
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yea i've actually tried that. When I do that, the error i get is undefined method `tasks_path' on the form

Comment: change the form params...i have updated my answer. as its presentation/tasks...you need to pass presentation first and then tasks to the form..check my answer.Let me know if it works :).

Comment: thanks! :) it does work. However, now the error i get is on the label, undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass

Comment: As i said,every presentation has a tasks,so verify that both presentation and tasks exists and then check their fields.You can use rails console to quickly check the models and their columns.Kindly Accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: tasks has a field called summary, i don't get why it states it doesnt have a field for summary when it is indeed a column

Comment: No,the error says that task is nil...so either presentation or task is nil.debug it..check it in rails console direclty.

Comment: I have debugged it. I put a binding.pry right before the label tag and I checked task and presentation. They both are not nil.